# Correlation on raining on weekends

Tags: probability

$50\%$ of raining on Saturday, $80\%$ of raining on Sunday. What is the range of probability for raining on weekend. And the correlation between raining on Saturday and Sunday.

The first part I could get:
$A$: *Raining on Saturday*
$B$: *Raining on Sunday*

$$
P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)\\
0 \leq P(A\cap B) \leq 0.5\\
0.8 \leq P(A\cup B)\leq 1
$$

How can I get correlation?